# no instance of variable R exists so that void conforms to R

Tags: java-8

I have requirement to format user identifier with dept and date as below. But I get error as "no instance of variable R exists so that void conforms to R" when using map function

```
public List<Users> formatUserIdentifier(String dept, String joinDate) {
users.stream().map(user -> {
                    return user.setIdentifier(user.getIdentifier() + "_" + dept + "_" + joinDate);
                });
return users;
}
```

Eg: Prior format, user = john
After format, user = john_CS_20210921

If I use forEach loop it works well. Can someone advise how to use map here, please?

Comment: Thas thet setter returns the user object ?

Comment: You should `forEach` instead of `map`. You use `map` when you want to transform 
 element to other type.

Comment: Or use `peek()` if stream terminates with a collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend doing it with a `forEach` loop or regular `for` loop. In this case, you don't need to return anything so the return type would be `void`.

```
public void formatUserIdentifier(String dept, String joinDate) {
       users.stream().forEach(user-> 
           user.setIdentifier(user.getIdentifier() + "_" + dept + "_" + joinDate));
       }
}
```

But here is how you might do it with `map`. You must create a new instance of the `User` class with the appropriate arguments. Those arguments must be the same from the current user class being processed in the stream.  So each newly created `User` instance will be just like the one processed except for the identifier change.

```
public List<User> formatUserIdentifier(String dept, String joinDate) {   
       return user.stream()
               .map(user-> new User(user.getIdentifier() + "_" + dept + "_" + joinDate,
                                    other user arguments here ...))
               .toList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `map()` in this case, but `peek()`.

Here is an example of how to use it:

```java
public List<Users> formatUserIdentifier(String dept, String joinDate) {
    return users.stream().peek(user -> user.setIdentifier(user.getIdentifier() + "_" + dept + "_" + joinDate));
}
```